# Sql more condition on the same row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi seems this is trivial question but somehow it isn't, i got simple where query

```
where ([Year] >= 2012 and [Month] >= 12) and ([Year] <= 2013 and [Month] < 1)
```

and this query exclude any rows cause there is condition month > 12 and month < 1, so how to do it that this will return row for 2012.12 so to check month >=12 only if year is 2012 and to check month < 1 only for those rows where year is 2013 ?

I should mention that my sql table has no dateTime fields only

```
[Year] [int] NOT NULL,
[Month] [int] NOT NULL,
[Value] [float] NOT NULL,
```

Comment: What does `Month < 1` mean? If you are regarding January as `0` then how can there be a Month `12`?

Comment: this means to get only rows for previous year it blocks rows from next years

Comment: Are you only trying to get rows from December 2012? If so you just need `[Year] = 2012 and [Month] = 12` If not please explain exactly which ones from 2013 you need.

Comment: Actually with condition `Month<1` will not setisfy for any valid month in database. As you described after in your question you want to check for the previous months in your desired query then you have to include year part as well ...

Comment: there fore i want like two condition to check, if year 2012 and month >= 12 and if year 2013 and month <2 should return two rows 2012.12 and 2013.1

Comment: We require more info about your *idiosyncratic* approach in order to help you.  At this point, the conditions `month > 12` and `month < 1` are meaningless to us.  What is the datatype of your Month column and what are the permissible values in that column?

Comment: Also, you need to PUNCTUATE your question properly instead of writing one long run-on sentence. `so how to do it...so to check`. If you question is simply `how to do it that this will return row for 2012.12` the answer is `where year = 2012 and month = 12`, ASSUMING your months run from 1 through 12 and not 0 through 11.

Answer (score 0):

`there fore i want like two condition to check, if year 2012 and month >= 12 and if year 2013 and month <2 should return two rows 2012.12 and 2013.1`

@kosnkov: I am making a guess here that you are asking how to find rows where the date is within a specified number of months from a starting date.  Are you familiar with DateDiff() function?  It requires a DateTime column.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794%28v=sql.90%29.aspx

Answer (score -2):

As per your requiremnet you need to check condition with `or` condition as below -

well one thing about [month] that month value will be from 1 to 12. it will never be less than 1 and also never be greater than 12. so for achiving your desired outout you can use below query -

```
where ([Year] >= 2012 and [Month] = 12) or ([Year] < 2013 and [Month] < 2)
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

For getting output as you commented we can concatenate the year and month part and can check as below -

```
where ([Year]*100+[Month] >= 201212 and [Year]*100+[month] < 201302)
```

this condition will give only record for year 2012 and month 12 or year 2013 and month less then 2

Comment: ok i improve query, it should be where ([Year] >= 2012 and [Month] = 12) or ([Year] <= 2013 and [Month] < 2) but this will return 2012.01 2012.12 and 2013.01 while only two last should be returned

Comment: I have missed the situation as you commented before writing the query.. so I have edited my post.. please check updated one.

Comment: Why I got down voted for this answer?
Please provide your valuable feedback also along with your votes (positive or negative).